# Strange auto completion in Google Colab on android

Tags: python, android, google-colaboratory

I have a strange behavior with Colab running on Samsung tablet.

If I type "np" I get "npnp" or if I type "np." I get "npnp."
see the link.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/bcDAm1oe2vvKM7zq6

Any idea what is wrong. I have disabled code completions but it has no effect.
Thanks.
Petro.

Comment: I have the same problem. Chrome Mobile on Android 12, using colab in Desktop mode